# How to split a file on "empty line" pattern, into an array of variables ? (only using native bash)

Tags: arrays, bash, split, newline

I'm actually using a bash script to work on a deep folder structure, and extracting informations (related-folder size, extracted text from config files, etc ...), to push them into a database to summarize.

"NO NEW PROCESS" is my rule on this script, since every folder leads to about 300 conf files, and I have about 10.000 folders ... so only native command please.

Here's a part of one input file that i'm actually trying to work with :

```
include_ldap_query
attrs mail
ssl_ciphers ALL
filter (mail=john.doe*)
name MyRequestName1
host myldaphost:30002
use_ssl no
passwd MyPassword
timeout 60
suffix ou=collaborators,ou=My Company,ou=people,dc=MyLdapContent,dc=MyCompany,dc=fr
user uid=MyUserID,ou=accounts,dc=MyLdapContent,dc=MyCompany,dc=fr
ssl_version sslv2
scope sub
select all

include_ldap_query
attrs mail
ssl_ciphers ALL
filter (mail=janedoe*)
name MyRequestName2
host myldaphost:30002
use_ssl no
passwd MyPassword
timeout 60
suffix ou=collaborators,ou=My Company,ou=people,dc=MyLdapContent,dc=MyCompany,dc=fr
user uid=MyUserID,ou=accounts,dc=MyLdapContent,dc=MyCompany,dc=fr
ssl_version sslv3
scope sub
select first

include_ldap_query
attrs mail
ssl_ciphers ALL
filter (mail=jimmy.page*)
name MyRequestName3
host myldaphost:30002
use_ssl no
passwd MyPassword
timeout 60
suffix ou=collaborators,ou=My Company,ou=people,dc=MyLdapContent,dc=MyCompany,dc=fr
user uid=MyUserID,ou=accounts,dc=MyLdapContent,dc=MyCompany,dc=fr
ssl_version sslv3
scope sub
```

I'd like to put those querys into an array, to work separately with each other.
how can i split on the empty line pattern ?

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly pure BASH but you can use `null RS` in awk for this splitting on an empty line:

```
awk '{print NR ":", $0}' RS= file
```

Answer (score 0):

**Pure bash**

You might use a blank line to trigger an array index increment.
In this example we assume the input is piped to stdin.
The layout in the array will be like:

```
ARRAY[0]="include_ldap_query |attrs mail|ssl_ciphers ALL|filter (mail=john.doe*)|..."
ARRAY[1]="include_ldap_query |attrs mail|ssl_ciphers ALL|filter (mail=janedoe*)|...."
```

This could do the job, i think.

```
#!/bin/bash

INDEX=0
while read LINE
do
  [ "$LINE" = "" ] && (( ++INDEX )) || ARRAY[$INDEX]="$ARRAY[$INDEX]""|$LINE"
done

# down here comes the rest of your code
# everything is in arrays by now
```